# Como enviar valores por GET aparte de los del formulario?

Tags: html, http, formularios, web

Tengo un formulario para enviar datos por `GET` y quiero enviar un dato adicional anexándolo a la URL, el codigo es:

```
<form action="/Libro?accion=salvar" method="get">

        <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="titulo"  name="titulo">

        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria">
        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios">

    </form>
```

Cuando le doy submit se envía la siguiente url:

```
Libro?titulo=Inferno&categoria=Literatura
```

Pero no se envía la variable `accion=salvar` que quiero enviar, no sé cómo enviar esa variable adicional a la otra página en la misma url.

Comment: Nunca debes mandar formularios por GET, se deben enviar por POST. Tarde o temprano encontrarás muchos problemas si continúas por ese camino,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Añade un campo `hidden`

```
<input type="hidden" name="accion" value="salvar">
```

Tú código completo:

```
<form action="/Libro" method="get">

    <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="titulo"  name="titulo">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="salvar"><!-- !! -->
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios">
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @aldanux

Answer (score 1):

Puedes enviarla de esta forma :

```
<input type='hidden' name='accion' value='salvar' />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @sioesi

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, en tu `action` no debes incluir el método `GET` por `URL`, ya estas declarando que vas a enviar el formulario por método `GET`.

Puedes incluir un `input` de tipo `hidden` y allí es donde añades el valor de salvar.

Aunque en vede utilizar el método `GET` utilizaría el método `POST`, la diferencia es la forma de enviar los datos, `GET` envía los datos usando la `URL` y `POST` las envía por entrada estándar y no muestra nada en tu `URL`.

```
<form action="./Libro" method="POST">

    <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="titulo"  name="titulo" />

    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria" />
    <br>

    <input type="hidden" name="tu_identificador" value="salvar" />

    <input type="submit" value="Guardar cambios" />

</form>
```

Comment: En primer lugar no se pasa el valor en el atributo `name` y segundo no tiene nada malo si lo envías por `GET` mientras que no sean datos sensibles... y si quieres que sea más seguro por `post` tienes que mandarlo por protocolo seguro `https`

Comment: @aldanux No le estoy deciendo que debe utilizar el metodo POST si lees bien la respuesta, le estoy diciendo que yo utilizaria el metodo POST, y en el name, se pasa el identificador por eso en value pongo el valor salva, quisas eso a quedado algo confuso. Y en ningun momento e dicho que sea mas seguro, ya que los dos son métodos del protocolo HTTP.